# Rewrite rule in nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, rewrite

I'm moving a PHP application from Apache to Nginx, using php-fpm. I'm almost done, except by a rewrite directive that I haven't been able to do in Nginx. The following is the excerpt from the Apache config that I need to port:

```
# Handle alianza.quehambre.cl
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^alianza\.quehambre\.cl [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(api|get)/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/get/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The full Nginx configuration is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/aarellano/6055932), including my current non-working attempt to write the above rules.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
server {
    server_name alianza.quehambre.cl;

    location / {

        location ~ ^/(api|get)/(.*) {
            # Whatever should happen at this point...
        }

        try_files $uri /index.php/get/$request_uri =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but I'm getting a 404. I enabled the rewrite_log, and I don't get any error.

Comment: Try removing the `=404` part, PHP has to handle that request then. Replace your `index.php` temporarily to check what's coming in, e.g. by doing `<?php header("content-type: text/plain"); print_r($_SERVER); ?>` so you get a sense of what's going on. Also check that your `fastcgi_params` are set correctly. This rewrite will most certainly destroy the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` variable. You'd have to set this to a constant: `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
    location ~ (api|get)/(.*) {
    }

    location / {
      if ($http_host ~* "^alianza\.quehambre\.cl"){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/get/$1 break;
      }
    }
```